# Multithreading In Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing

I am having trouble locating how to multithread in Flask. Right now the only things that I have seen is a message passing libary (celery) and the implemenation with django.

What I am trying to do is create a Poller thread that will poll some external API, and also have the flask app still take in requests.

I know that Python has a global interpreter lock as to not allow for multiple system threads but I wanted to know if it can be worked around

Example of what I want to do:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


def poller_function():
    itr = 0
    while(True):
        itr += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Flask('my_app')
    poller = AppContextThread(target=poller_function)
    poller.start()
    app.run()
    poller.join()
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem right now. Did you find any answer? Thanks!